# InvalidCast Exception from Int32 to DateTime - but where?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using the following raw SQL code through NHibernate, and I can't find more sample code to compare with, but it blows up with an InvalidCastException (Int32 to DateTime)

```
var query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*), MIN(Created), MAX(Created)" + 
                                   " FROM MyStuff WHERE Created < :deadline")
                   .SetDateTime("deadline", deadline)
                   .UniqueResult();
```

Now, I am pretty sure that deadline is in fact of type DateTime (the method wouldn't even take any other type obviously), and as far as I understand I do not force a type on the result, so where is this conversion coming from?

Comment: What query executed at sql side? Try to check it with profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever we want NHibernate to load data from DB, we must think about the ex-post result processing. Mostly, aliasing, to properly help find out which value from record-set (DB) belongs to which value in result-set (C#).

So this simple adjustment "AS Alias" is the way to go:

```
var query = session
    .CreateSQLQuery("SELECT COUNT(*)     AS Count,   " +
                   "        MIN(Created) AS MinDate, " +
                   "        MAX(Created) AS MaxDate  " +
                   " FROM MyStuff WHERE Created < :deadline")                
    .SetDateTime("deadline", deadline)
    ;
var result = query
    .UniqueResult<object[]>()
    ;

var count   = (int)     result[0];
var minDate = (DateTime)result[1];
var maxDate = (DateTime)result[2];
```

Once we did that, we can make it even easier, using a DTO

```
public class ResultDto
{
    public virtual int Count { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime MinDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime MaxDate { get; set; }
}
```

A result statement:

```
var result = query
    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<ResultDto>())
    .UniqueResult<ResultDto>()
```